# Aggregate Formula in Google Sheet using wildcards

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I'm trying to copy and paste an excel formula I use to categorize data into Google Sheets and struggle as the formula doesn't work.

I have two sheets:

The **Referral sheet** contains all the referral sources such as google etc. 
The **Categories Sheet** contains all the categories that I want to use and the sources within them.

So the categories sheet is formatted as follows:

```
Column A     Column B  
Source       Categories  
*google*     Search 
*facebook*   Social Media
```

I thereby use the * as a fuzzy search within an url.

In excel I use the following formula that works

```
=IF(A4="","",IFERROR(INDEX(Categories!$B$2:$B$113,AGGREGATE(14,6,--(COUNTIF(A4,Categories!$A:$A)>=1)*ROW(Categories!$B:$B)-1,1)),"Others"))
```

Can you help me on how I need to re-write it that it also works for Google?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your Excel's formula is that `AGGREGATE` is not a Google Sheets function. While both apps belongs to the same "family" and there are a lot of common functions / features there are other that are unique to each app.

Maybe [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) could work for you

Related

- [Using AGGREGATE formula on Google Sheets - Finding the correct result based on 3 columns of criteria](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121867/88163)

Reference

- [Google Sheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)